# add_meta_box showing blank screen in my page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, meta-boxes

I am working on the plugin and getting issues in `add_meta_box`.

```
// Page URL- 

http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=testingpages&action=edit

//Plugin page code

if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
        include('admin/views/view-edit.php');
}
```

The below is code, I am using on the `view-edit.php` page

```
function adding_custom_meta_boxes($post)
{
    add_meta_box(
        'testingpages',
        __('My Meta Box'),
        'render_my_meta_box',
        'page',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes');

function render_my_meta_box()
{
    // code here
}
```

i am getting blank screen. Any idea where is the issue/

**Edited.**

from `add_action('add_meta_boxes_post', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes');`

to   `add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes');`

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this action and try this:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'adding_custom_meta_boxes');
```

Comment: I also tried that but same issue

Comment: Follow this documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/

Comment: Also check your meta box enable or not by screen options, check the screenshot:  https://prnt.sc/MXT_4OW5hiGv

Comment: I don't have a screen option, As I am working on a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The meta box is available only for existing and custom post types, not admin pages.

There is a way to make it work on the options page. [Create option page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Check out some examples: [here](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/757903)